# Generate an unique 4 digit id in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Very much new to Lambda.

I am trying to generate a 4 digit random unique id which will be used as a primary key for DynamoDB. (my table will only ever contain 9000 rows)

Now I usually do like

```
list(range(100))
list.shuffle()
```

but how can I achieve the same in a Lambda function ?

thanks !

Comment: Be aware that this could lead to a duplicate key overwriting an older item. To solve this, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda functions can run your code (pretty-much) as normal. So, you can continue to use that method if you wish.

To generate a random 4-character hex string, I like to use:

```py
import uuid

print(uuid.uuid4().hex[0:4])
```

Comment: I think this is my lack of understanding (I am reading further), I thought Lambdas are stateless ? This lambda function will be invoked exactly once a day.

Also, since we are only working with 4 digit random numbers, the chance of collisions will increase significantly which is what I am trying to to avoid.

Comment: If you want a guaranteed unused number, the use an **Atomic Counter** in DynamoDB. It can increment and return the new value in one operation.

Comment: @anilit99 yes its stateless, to have a state you'd need to use a database or some sort of storage.